# Woocommerce manually insert transaction data

Tags: database, transactions, woocommerce, reporting

We are trying to migrate our existing product and order data to woocommerce. We will also periodically sync this additional data.

Due to performance concerns we are unable to use the Woocommerce API for this and have opted instead for manual database entries.

Everything appears to be working except the values of the order in the Woocommerce reporting, which do not seem to be picked up. We can see the amount of products sold from the orders without issue.

To set the order total we are adding a row into the wp_postmeta table with the key '_order_total'. Is there any other field that is required for Woocommerce to see the total?

Am I missing something else somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce > System Status > Tools > Clear transients

Also looks like `_payment_method` and `_payment_method_title` need to be populated.

For reference I'm using `_order_version = 2.6.4`